# How to handle data when using classes - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I am currently working within CodeIgniter and I am struggling to understand how to properly use *Anemic or Rich Entity Classes* within my programming.

I am looking to create an anemic entity that has getters/setters, but I am wondering how this all works.

*For instance:*

I can use the object to set and get information while an instance of the object is being created for the first time, but when retrieving information from my database how do I return the information into an object so that I can use the objects methods?

I have heard of using Doctrine to map objects to a relational database but I have already created the database schema I want to use and I am unsure about getting Doctrine to map to an existing database.

*I have thought about trying:*

- Using the `__construct` function to set all of the objects properties
  using the array I get from the SQL query, which seems improper.
- Creating an instance of the object and setting all the objects
  properties to the values of the array I get from the SQL query, which seems tedious.
- Creating a method within the object that takes the array I get from
  the SQL query and assigns all of the values to the proper object
  properties, which seems okay.

*But my question is:* **Is there a universally accepted practice for doing this?** (other than Doctrine)

Comment: 1) you can get doctrine to map existing schema, just define it same as it is with annotations. 2) if you are going for selfmade solutions, its good to have naming convention (php - $myField, db - my_field) - then you can call functions defined by variable (loop through all fields in result, for every field call `$fn = 'set'.$fieldName; $obj->$fn($fieldValue);` etc.) 3) use reflection

Comment: All three of your options are possible and sensible.

Comment: codeigniter using active record orm as I remember which allows to use objects

Comment: @bxN5 Would that just using the custom_result_object() function and specifying which class you want to return the object to?

Comment: @AdamM https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-arrays - you can already pass a string to the result method which represents a class to instantiate for each result object

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Doctrine or other ORM tool, but if you want to DIY, here is small example of using reflection.

```
<?php

class Foo {
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function getId(){ return $this->id; }

    public function getName(){ return $this->name; }

    public function setName($name){ return $this->name = $name; }
}

$dataFromDb = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'John'
    ]
];


foreach ($dataFromDb as $row) {
    $foo = new Foo();
    $ref = new ReflectionClass('Foo');

    foreach ($row as $propName => $propValue) {
        $prop = $ref->getProperty($propName);
        $prop->setAccessible(true);
        $prop->setValue($foo, $propValue);
    }

    var_dump($foo);
}
```

Comment: Yeah so its basically just create functions to manipulate the data you want from db->class and from class->db ?

Comment: Well, you can make just one function which handle it and resolve class by table name. Main point of using reflection is that you can keep private props without setter (eg. Id should be without setter)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand. What is the difference between using the `ReflectionClass` and just instantiating a class and using one of the classes methods to correctly set the properties? How does the ReflectionClass avoid having to set the id?

Comment: @AdamM In an entity, there should not be method setId(), id is an autogenerated value, so you should not be able to directly set it